# Постановка тире между частями сложного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Скотти был уже немолод, и, хотя он получал приличное жалование за то, что ничего не делал, он понимал, что скоро ему придётся уйти в отставку. «Было бы неплохо, — думал он, — если бы лорд Ванек решил отблагодарить меня за миллионы, которые принёс Валенвудский контракт, и сделал бы меня партнёром. Или, по крайней мере, выделил бы мне небольшую долю из этих денег…».
>
> Декумус Скотти не умел просить о поощрениях такого **рода — вот почему** до своего ослепительного успеха с Валенвудским контрактом он был всего лишь жалким клерком.

Чем можно объяснить постановку тире в выделенном мною месте? Корректно ли ставить его? Текст является переводом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае тире ставится, т.к. вторая часть БСП имеет присоединительное значение.

Ср.: Именно в ту ночь я стала взрослой – так мне кажется сейчас (Д. Рубина. Окна);

Из верхнего отверстия чума бил вверх столб туманного красного света – это в чуме горел очаг (А. Иванов. Золото бунта).

https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=79